# Changing the order of the items in a dataview webpart

Tags: list

I have Order field in my list which I used to align the items in a data-view webpart using 'Sortby'.Now if I need to change the order of a particular item in that list I have to change the order of all the items in the list.Is there a way where I could only change the order value of the required item, and it automatically updates the Order value of rest of the items.Hope you people understood what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think any option available meeting your requirement, you can make use of "modified" and "created" date fields to control sort order.

Comment: Is there a possibility to have it done using workflow?

Comment: if you have 50,000 items and you iterate in a workflow, then expect performance issues.